# Python Tkinter (Beginner level)

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I need some help over here!

```
import tkinter as tk


class CountVisitors:
    def __int__(self, master):
        self.master = master

        self.button1 = tk.Button(self.master, text="Count", command=self.counting)

        self.button1.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

        self.button_click = 0

    def counting(self):
        self.button_click += 1
        print(self.button_click)


def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    CountVisitors(root)
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

when I try to run this code, it prompts me an error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
    File "C:/Users/Anson/PycharmProjects/improvement/improvement.py", line 26, in <module> main() 
    File "C:/Users/Anson/PycharmProjects/improvement/improvement.py", line 21, in main CountVisitors(root) 
    TypeError: object() takes no parameters
```

What does it mean?

Comment: Which line raises the error?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Anson/PycharmProjects/improvement/improvement.py", line 26, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/Anson/PycharmProjects/improvement/improvement.py", line 21, in main
    CountVisitors(root)
TypeError: object() takes no parameters

Comment: I am so confused.

Comment: get into the habit of including the full traceback. Without it we have to run the program ourselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `__init__` is misspelled (missing an 'i').

change the line:

```
def __int__(self, master):
```

to:

```
def __init__(self, master):
```

Comment: Remember to accept the answer if it solved your problem. :)

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much!:)